# Laravel Sanctum returns 401 Unauthenticated

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm currently implementing remote API access using Bearer tokens for a project. Personal API tokens are created using Laravel Jetstream and their respective permissions set, but when fetching Sanctum returns 401.

(Laravel Inertia Stack)

If I remove the auth:sanctum as middleware, and call auth('sanctum')->user() I do get the user associated with the token.

In a blank project only setup with Jetstream the API Bearer auth works.

At this point I've basically tried every fix I could find. Setting STATEFUL_DOMAIN, SESSION_DOMAIN, CORS, even replacing Sanctum v2 with v3, setting Referer, you name it.

Sadly, starting the project from scratch isn't possible. Yes: It has been created with Jetstream from the beginning.